# How do I automatically remove focus from searchview in android app after clicking on it

Tags: android, lost-focus, lostfocus

I m making book finder app.
step1: i clicked on search button and activity is waiting for my book title

[image: k]

step2: i input some book title
[image: k2]

[image: k3]

step3: the focus still stays on this search button, i have to click on screen to make it go away.

**is there way to automatically loose focus on last widget i clicked on?**

Answer (score 2):

You probably just want to call `requestFocus()` on your book list whenever a search completes (however, if there are no results, you may want to re-open your search box, or do so after a delay). There is also a `OnFocusChangedListener` which might be of help if requesting focus on your list after serving up results does't work for some reason.